Graph Neural Network Pooling for keeping the same shape of node without batching
I want to add a pooling layer on my model. I want to preserve the num of node as I m doing node prediction without batching.
import torch
from torch_geometric.nn import global_add_pool
# Assume your input tensor is x with shape (num_nodes, num_node_features)
x = torch.randn(10, 10)  # Example tensor with (num_nodes, num_node_features) = (10, 10)
# Apply global_add_pool
x_pooled = global_add_pool(x, batch=None)

x_pooled (1,10)
But I want a pooling method to give me (10,x)

I think you're confused about terms. The whole point of pooling in graph neural networks is to combine representations from different nodes. "Pooling" to "preserve the num of nodes" doesn't make sense. If you want an operation to change the feature dimension of the node tensor, you can just use a matmul
